# GetAncestor: Undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2005, win32gui

I'm using Visual Studio 6 for backward compatibility reasons and I need
to use `GetAncestor()` like this to create a dll :

```
HWND ancestorhandle = GetAncestor(myvar, 2);
```

I've included these header files:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "offlinelib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
```

As per the documentation:

[GetAncestor function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633502.aspx)

But while compiling, I get an error:

```
GetAncestor: Undeclared identifier
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using precompiled headers `stdafx.h` **must** be the first `#include`.

Comment: Didn't help...please see the reply to Mr.C64

Comment: Can't you make an MCVE? Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `#include "stdafx.h"` (precompiled header) up, making it the *first* include line.

Comment: I still get the same error after your suggested change: See here for the complete code http://pastebin.com/UA931nJu

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding

```
#ifdef WINVER
#undef WINVER
#endif
#define WINVER 0x500
```

on top of stdafx.h

Comment: It would be better to set the `WINVER` value in your project settings instead of in your code.  But in any case `WINVER` should already be set to `0x500` (win2K) by default, so something else in your project is setting it to a lower value or `#undef`ing it, so you should find that something and remove that instead.

Comment: You should delete the question. It's pointless. This answer shows why. It's only relevant to code that only you can see.